# help for user permissions and file directory access mac OS Sierra

Tags: permissions, users, directory-structure, non-root-user, permission-denied

Im trying to sort my usrers and usser permission in terminal to install Ruby gems and other libraries, but getting nowhere because of the permissions denied errors. Steps I tried:

1. Had a call with apple to sort out my user permissions, executed this command

   `diskutil resetUserPermissions / id -u`

NOTE: id -u was in `` (code editing strips it out here). It did not work. still getting permission errors.

2. Tried to run Postgres (installed from GUI), getting

   `FATAL FATAL:  role "Berzins" does not exist); (FATAL:  data directory 
   "/Users/Linards/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6" has group 
   or world access
   DETAIL:  Permissions should be u=rwx (0700)`

In terminal I am:

```
Linards:~ Berzins$ whoami
Berzins
Linards:~ Berzins$
```

3. Ran the follwing in terminal:

`Linards:~ Berzins$ dscl . -read /Groups/admin    /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist: 
No such file or directory
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000050
GroupMembers: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000 6F8DC3A8-D4B6-4175-B24A-1A99756706FA
GroupMembership: root Linards Berzins Linards Linards Berzins
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 80
RealName: Administrators
RecordName: admin BUILTIN\Administrators
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
SMBSID: S-1-5-32-544
Linards:~ Berzins$ dscl . -read /Groups/staff
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist: No such file or directory
AppleMetaNodeLocation: /Local/Default
GeneratedUID: ABCDEFAB-CDEF-ABCD-EFAB-CDEF00000014
GroupMembers: FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA00000000 6F8DC3A8-D4B6-4175-B24A-1A99756706FA FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000000ED FFFFEEEE-DDDD-CCCC-BBBB-AAAA000000EE
GroupMembership: root Berzins _xcsbuildagent _xcscredserver
Password: *
PrimaryGroupID: 20
RealName: Staff
RecordName: staff BUILTIN\Users
RecordType: dsRecTypeStandard:Groups
SMBSID: S-1-5-32-545
Linards:~ Berzins$`

AND this:

`Linards:~ Berzins$ id
uid=501(Berzins) gid=20(staff) 
groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)
Linards:~ Berzins$`

4. Then ran the following:

`Linards:~ Berzins$ dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership Linards
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist: No such file or directory
<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)
Linards:~ Berzins$ dscl . append /Groups/admin GroupMembership Berzins
/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServicesLocal.plist: No such file or directory
<main> attribute status: eDSPermissionError
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14120 (eDSPermissionError)
Linards:~ Berzins$`

Now Im massively stuck.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From an offline discussion, I understood you were trying to install postgresql on macOS.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/):

> Homebrew
>
> PostgreSQL can also be installed on macOS using Homebrew. Please see
>   the Homewbrew documentation for information on how to install
>   packages.

1. Install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/): 
   `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. Install postgresql from terminal: `brew install postgresql`.

My output:

```
$ brew install postgresql
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!


==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/postgresql-9.6.3.sierra.bot
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring postgresql-9.6.3.sierra.bottle.tar.gz
==> Using the sandbox
==> /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3/bin/initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
==> Caveats
If builds of PostgreSQL 9 are failing and you have version 8.x installed,
you may need to remove the previous version first. See:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/2510

To migrate existing data from a previous major version (pre-9.0) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/upgrading.html

To migrate existing data from a previous minor version (9.0-9.5) of PostgreSQL, see:
  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html

  You will need your previous PostgreSQL installation from brew to perform `pg_upgrade`.
  Do not run `brew cleanup postgresql` until you have performed the migration.

To have launchd start postgresql now and restart at login:
  brew services start postgresql
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.3: 3,259 files, 36.6MB
```

You could also just download the .app and use that.

Comment: It sounds like the OP had managed to install Postgres, but was having permissions problems; this Answer doesn't appear to address any permissions issues.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, that is all nice and straight forward what you suggested, however as Jeff pointed out, im having the permissions errors on my system. Cheers